# Adjusting Order Quantities in Magento

Tags: magento

Im hoping someone could confirm that my process is correct for adjusting the quantities of a placed order.. e.g.

A customer orders the following: 4 x CD’s say @ £5.49 each and selects UK Mainland standard delivery. This gives a total order value of £27.95 (£21.96 goods + £5.99 p&p;).

· Let’s say we have only one of these CD’s in stock (and can’t get any more), so we contact the customer who instructs us to send one CD and cancel the remaining three. This gives a new total order value of £9.48 (£5.49 goods + £3.99 p&p;)

To process this order I have done the following:

1. Admin > Sales > Orders > View pending order 100000056
2. Information > Invoice. In the ‘New Invoice’ page I have changed the ‘Qty to Invoice’ to 1 > Update Qtys. (In practice this should change the Grand Total to £9.48 but is showing a total of £11.48, because the higher shipping charge of £5.99 is still being applied and cannot be updated as far as I can see). Not Capture > Submit Invoice
3. Invoice > Authorise £9.48 (the correct total) > Confirm Authorise > Capture > Send Invoice email. (The Invoice email shows an incorrect total of £11.48! Anyone know why this ?)
4. To correct £2.00 shipping overcharge: Invoice > Credit Memo > Refund Shipping £1.702 (excluding VAT) > Refund Offline. (There’s something wrong here, as the Credit Memo is calculating the VAT on £1.702 as 0.89p – it should be 0.298p! is this a magento bug?)
5. Invoice > Deliver > Quantity to Ship changed to 1 > Submit Delivery > Send Tracking Information
6. To cancel remainder of order which is out of stock: Information > Cancel. (I don’t know if this is correct, but it’s the only way I can find which cancels the balance of the order)

Answer (score 1):

If the order is fresh, (e.g. no extraordinary history to track), you could "edit" the order. That will actually cancel the first record and create a new one where you can reflect correct shipping, quantities, etc.

You would need to request their payment data again if they used a credit card, but if you're contacting the customer anyway, that's a perfect opportunity to get it done.